# How to efficiently sort the first items of an iterable?

Tags: sorting, python-3.x

I am using a big structure with a lot of data: a "Table" object. It has basic functionality like being iterable. It iterate over a collection of items that all have a `.get_norm()` method. To do so it uses two indexers: `rank_indexer` and `i_rank_indexer`. To get item number i I basically call `self.content[self.i_rank_indexer[i]]`. These two indexers are inverses of each other, and I have to make them stay that way.

What I want is being able to get the 300 first items among all the 15000 stored in self.content. Currently, I am doing the following:

```
def sort(self):
        scta = [0-self.content[self.i_rank_indexer[r]].get_norm() for r in range(self.cardinal)]
        npa = np.argsort(scta)
        self.i_rank_indexer = {x:self.i_rank_indexer[npa[x]] for x in range(len(npa))}
        self.rank_indexer = {self.i_rank_indexer[key]:key for key in self.i_rank_indexer}
```

The problem is that by doing this I am sorting a 15000 length array, which is way more complex that what I need (extracting the first 300 elements). What would be the most efficient way to do that ? I don't need to keep the rank_indexer system, but I must keep a way to access an element from it's rank.

Comment: Using a built-in sort of 15000 elements is probably much more efficient than any explicit loop approach to get the best 300.

Comment: It is, I would like a built-in approach to get the best 300, if it is possible.

Comment: Sorting with a built-in method is already blazingly fast, I'm not sure if there is much motivation for writing code to get something like the top 300. There is a good chance that the most efficient way in Python to get the top 300 *is* to first sort the whole list. Unless this is a bottleneck, I don't think that there is much motivation in worrying about it. 15000 items isn't so much that memory is an issue. If it is an issue, you can implement some of the algorithms in: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_sorting

Comment: It takes a few minutes for me, nothing "balzingly fast" here. And later I may need way more items than 15000.

Comment: A few minutes to sort 15000 elements? There must be something else going on with your code. I can't imagine that it is the sorting which is the bottle neck.

Comment: As an experiment, I created a list `randvects` which consists of 15,000 lists of length 3, each of which contains 3 randomly generated numbers. I then evaluated `best = sorted(randvects,key = lambda x: sum(x))[:300]` -- which gives me the 300 vectors whose *sum* is as small as possible. It takes just a small fraction of a second to find these 300. If you benchmark your code, you will (I think) discover that very, very little of it is spent in the line `npa = np.argsort(scta)`.

Comment: The line which take the most of the time is `scta = [0-self.content[self.i_rank_indexer[r]].get_norm() for r in range(self.cardinal)]`, so I guess I have to find a way to simplify `.get_norm` and stop worrying about the sorting. Thank you !